# PHPMailer accepting raw file name as attachment, but not as variable

Tags: php, phpmailer, attachment

I try to build a PHP script in order to send mail with attachment, using PHPMailer module.

When I put the raw file name into this line:

```
$docpath = "/tmp/document.pdf"; 
$mail->addAttachment($docpath);
```

It works perfectly; the file is attached and the mail is sent.

The problem occurs when I put the file name into a variable, like below:

```
$docpath = "/tmp/$attachmentname"; 
$mail->addAttachment($docpath);
```

It returns this error message:

```
Could not access file: /tmp/document.pdf
```

I tried with exactly the same file, nothing changed between the two trials...

I tried to change the syntax by adding quotes, like below:

```
$docpath = "/tmp/$attachmentname";
$mail->addAttachment("'".$docpath."'");
```

But same result, or almost:

```
Could not access file: '/tmp/document.pdf'
```

I finally tried this syntax:

```
$docpath = "/tmp/" . $attachmentname ."";
```

But no way...:

```
Could not access file: /tmp/document.pdf
```

The correct name is displayed in the error message, whereas the file did not move from the /tmp/ directory, and kept the same permissions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if there's some whitespace character in the variable, like trailing spaces, line breaks or similar. Do a `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($docpath); echo '</pre>';exit;` and check the output for spaces/line breaks. The first example will work if the variable contains an identical string.

Comment: in line with @MagnusEriksson's comment, `trim($docpath)` can easily help determine if there's any extra spaces etc. before or after.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson your command returned:
```
string(57) "/tmp/document.pdf
"
```

So yes indeed there is a line break at the end of the file name ...
Is there a php command to remove line break from a variable?

I tried to put this command but apparently did not work:
```
exec("sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/".'\n'."//g' attachmentname.txt > temp_attachmentname.txt && mv temp_attachmentname.txt attachmentname.txt");

Comment: As you see, that string ends with a blank space, which the file you're trying to use probably doesn't have in it's name. Do: `$docpath = '/tmp/' . trim($attachmentname);` and it should remove all leading and trailing white spaces.

Comment: This is a line break, not a blank space but line break does not appear in my comment :(
Your command worked well, thank you!

Comment: If the string that contains `/tmp/document.pdf` has 57 bytes then you have much more than a simple trailing line break.